# Javascript - replacing a div with another random div (buttons not working in the new div)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My overall objective is to create a test based on images. But i am stuck at an early stage. The idea is that an image appears and the user has to click on a button to choose the correct answer. Which ever button they click, the image is replaced randomly by another image. The problem I am having, is that when the image is replaced randomly by a new image, the buttons (in the same div as the new image) do not work. So the user can only use the buttons in the first div and then when this div is replaced, they can't get past the new random div. I am new to the forum.. but I would very grateful if someone can help me.

Here is my html.

```
<div id = 'suitcase'> 
   <img src ='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Suitcase_750x500.jpg' width = '400'/> 
   <ul> <button id = 'correct1'> suitcase </button>  &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'incorrect1'> backpack </button> &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'incorrect1'> handbag </button> </ul>
</div>;

<div id = 'printer'> 
   <img src = 'http://cdn2.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/reviews/3598061/HP_Envy_5640_e-All-in-One.jpg' width = '400'/> 
   <ul> <button id = 'correct2'> printer </button>  &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'incorrect2'> photocopier </button> &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'incorrect2'> computer </button> </ul>
</div>;

<div id = 'desk'>
   <img src = 'https://www.directofficesupply.co.uk/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/H4P3.jpg' width = '400'/>
   <ul> <button class = 'incorrect3'> printer </button>  &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'correct3'> desk </button> &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'incorrect3'> computer </button> </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript and JQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#printer").hide();
});

$(window).load(function() {
  $("#desk").hide();
});

var image1 = document.getElementById("desk").innerHTML;
var image2 = document.getElementById("suitcase").innerHTML;
var image3 = document.getElementById("printer").innerHTML;

var imageList = [image1, image2, image3]

function getRandomImage() {
  var random = imageList[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageList.length)];
  return random;
}

var randomImage = getRandomImage();


$("#correct1").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "blue"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#suitcase").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);

  $("#correct2").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background": "blue"
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#printer").html(randomImage);
    }, 500);
  });

  $("#correct3").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background": "blue"
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#desk").html(randomImage);
    }, 500);
  });

});

$(".incorrect1").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "red"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#suitcase").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);
});


$("#correct2").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "blue"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#printer").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);
});

$(".incorrect2").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "red"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#printer").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);
});

$("#correct3").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "blue"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#desk").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);
});

$(".incorrect3").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "red"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#desk").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);
});
```

What am I doing wrong??!!

Comment: This code is in dire need of indentation

Comment: Is there a point on having multiple buttons instead of reusing the same for all DIVs?? Also people could cheat by looking at your code just by the names of you buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote the codes, Only the buttons which are loaded by the document are known. the generated buttons wouldn't be known. you have to use `.on` or `.delegate`

I write a sample here. You can change all of yours.

The way you can use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
$("#correct2").on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({
        "background": "blue"
    });setTimeout(function(){
        $("#printer").html(randomImage);
    },
    500);
});
```

The way you can use [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (Which is deprecated in jQuery v3):

```
$('body').delegate('#correct2', 'click', function(){
    $(this).css({
        "background": "blue"
    });setTimeout(function(){
        $("#printer").html(randomImage);
    },
    500);
});
```

Comment: .click bind its event on document load. If the button is being removed then added back, it wont have any event listener attached resulting in the first example not working.

Comment: @FelipeSkinner, thanks for clarifying. I exactly meant what you said. Feel free to edit my answer with your explanation :)

Comment: @FelipeSkinner, or Moktaba - please could you give me an example?

Comment: @Oliver, why an example?! I put a fixed code piece of your existing code. Just do the same for your other button listeners.

Comment: @Oliver, So, you have to make a fiddle for such case. Otherwise, it's not easy to help more

Comment: @Mojtaba... here is the jsfiddle... sorry i'm new to this.. thanks alot for your help: https://jsfiddle.net/1wm23cx0/3/

Comment: @FelipeSkinner, could you please edit Moktaba's answer with your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I will do an example for the first case only, once you understand it becomes easy to replicate.

Given the first example we will fix the "incorrect" button.

html

```
<div id = 'suitcase'> 
   <img src ='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Suitcase_750x500.jpg' width = '400'/> 
   <ul> <button id = 'correct1'> suitcase </button>  &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'incorrect1'> backpack </button> &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class = 'incorrect1'> handbag </button> </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
$(".incorrect1").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "red"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#suitcase").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);
});
```

The issue here is that the click event is being bound to the "incorrect1" button on the document load. Once you remove it and replaces with another button, even if it has the same html class/id, the event was already bound and it does not "re-bound" automatically.

My suggestion is that you bound the event to an outer element and then filter it's call to the "incorrect1" selector (read more about [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function):

```
$("#suitcase").on("click", ".incorrect1", function() {
  $(this).css({
    "background": "red"
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#suitcase").html(randomImage);
  }, 500);
});
```

So, what's happening here? I'm binding a event to the whole suitcase div. Then I'm specifying the event type as "click" and telling it to check only clicks on any elements inside my "#suitcase" that matches my selector ".incorrect".

This way, the event is bound to a element that does not get removed ( your suitcase div ). Even if you remove all the children nodes there and replaces then, the event listener is bound to the outer div, so the issue I presented earlier is no longer a problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your last post helped alot.. but its still not working. However, it is a step closer to success because the button on the random Image is changing color, but it doesn´t change the image... here is my updated code.. hopefully it will be easier to read now

Comment: (here is a jsfiddle with my updated code)

https://jsfiddle.net/gmyfxcu5/    (thanks again)